# Weird LNK2001 errors after migration to VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2019

After moving my code from VS2017 to VS2019 I stumbled into strange linker behaviour -- it seems like it references objects from static library that it shouldn't have (which in turn refer to symbols that can't be resolved). Basically, I end up with this:

```
1>tools.lib(object_storage_azure.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl azure::storage::operation_context::operation_context(void)" (__imp_??0operation_context@storage@azure@@QEAA@XZ)
1>tools.lib(object_storage_azure.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: class Concurrency::task<void> __cdecl azure::storage::cloud_block_blob::upload_block_list_async_impl(class std::vector<class azure::storage::block_list_item,class std::allocator<class azure::storage::block_list_item> > const &,class azure::storage::access_condition const &,class azure::storage::blob_request_options const &,class azure::storage::operation_context,class Concurrency::cancellation_token const &,bool,class std::shared_ptr<class azure::storage::core::timer_handler>)" (__imp_?upload_block_list_async_impl@cloud_block_blob@storage@azure@@AEAA?AV?$task@X@Concurrency@@AEBV?$vector@Vblock_list_item@storage@azure@@V?$allocator@Vblock_list_item@storage@azure@@@std@@@std@@AEBVaccess_condition@23@AEBVblob_request_options@23@Voperation_context@23@AEBVcancellation_token@5@_NV?$shared_ptr@Vtimer_handler@core@storage@azure@@@7@@Z)
1>tools.lib(object_storage_azure.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class Concurrency::task<void> __cdecl azure::storage::cloud_block_blob::upload_from_stream_async(class Concurrency::streams::basic_istream<unsigned char>,unsigned __int64,class azure::storage::access_condition const &,class azure::storage::blob_request_options const &,class azure::storage::operation_context,class Concurrency::cancellation_token const &)" (__imp_?upload_from_stream_async@cloud_block_blob@storage@azure@@QEAA?AV?$task@X@Concurrency@@V?$basic_istream@E@streams@5@_KAEBVaccess_condition@23@AEBVblob_request_options@23@Voperation_context@23@AEBVcancellation_token@5@@Z)
... // and so forth
```

`tools.lib` is my own static library and it contains a lot of code, with 99% of it not being used by project being compiled. In particular, nothing from `object_storage_azure.obj` is being used for sure.

So, running linker with `/VERBOSE` produces this:

```
1>Starting pass 1
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprt
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:atls.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ole32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:shell32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:oleaut32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:shlwapi.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:comsuppw.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCMRT.LIB
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSCOREE
1>
1>Searching libraries
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\winhttp.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\ws2_32.lib:
...
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\odbccp32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\***my-path***\tools.lib:
1>      Found "public: virtual char const * __cdecl std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UEBAPEBDXZ)
1>        Referenced in stdafx.obj
1>        Loaded tools.lib(treescan_json.obj)            <--------- O_O
1>      Found "public: virtual char const * __cdecl std::bad_weak_ptr::what(void)const " (?what@bad_weak_ptr@std@@UEBAPEBDXZ)
1>        Referenced in stdafx.obj
1>        Loaded tools.lib(object_storage_azure.obj)     <--------- O_O
...
```

Basically, for some mysterious reason some STL references were resolved to (otherwise unreferenced) object files in my static lib (and those subsequently pulled in a whole world of stuff that can't be resolved).

Not sure if it is related, but project being compiled is a `/clr` dll; everything uses v142 toolset and 10.0.17763.0 SDK.

What is the proper way to address this issue?

Comment: How did you build that ``tools.lib``? Why does it have STL functions in it? Was it built with "static CRT linking" or otherwise includes a copy of the STL libs?  Try from a VS Developer Command Prompt running ``dumpbin /linkermember tools.lib`` and make sure it doesn't have a copy of STL in it.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn everything uses `/MD` (linking CRT dynamically) and `/Gy`. I imagine it contains STL function because of inlining, but it wasn't a problem in VS2017. In fact, `/VERBOSE` output of VS2017 shows the same picture, but for some reason it doesn't lead to unresolved symbols (they just never get mentioned). It feels like `/Gy` gets ignored by VS2019 -- it tries to resolve every symbol mentioned in `.obj` that got pulled by that resolved STL reference

Comment: What is the VS 2019 full version you are using? You might want to post a bug report to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html via Report a Problem. In general bits built by VS 2017 should link with a VS 2019 program.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn VS 16.6.5. I can't believe no one hit this problem, can't find anything in google either. I guess I will try to reproduce it using some trivial code and submit to MS... linker output is weird -- mentions some "Search transition"s of `<symbol>` to `__t2m@<symbol>`... :\

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Huh... Looks like `/clr` affects inlining of `std::exception::what` (switches it off), so CLD dll ends up searching for this symbol in linked libs. And it stumbles upon such export/. Problem is that when I switch toolset (v141 -> v142) smth changes in the static library (order of objects?) and said symbols now gets discovered in different `.obj` file, causing different set of dependencies to be pulled in...

Comment: @C.M. It is not clear if you rebuilt everything (program *and* libs) with the same VS version and toolset. See the caveat under the 3rd bullet point at [C++ binary compatibility between Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019) about static libraries and `/GL` objects.

Comment: @dxiv Everything is built by the same VS version with same flags (with exception of `/clr` for the dll that causes problems). I isolated and reproduced the problem with trivial code, will make another post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The happens because linker looks for certain symbols (e.g. `std::exception::what`) that normally get inlined (but not when `/clr` is in effect) and finds them in random object file of user static library (pulling in all dependencies said object file has). Switching to VS2019 simply changes the order of object files in said library. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289255/linking-static-native-library-to-managed-c-project-pulls-unused-and-unexpecte).