# Linking static native library to managed C++ project pulls unused (and unexpected) dependencies in

Tags: visual-c++, clr, managed-c++

**Synopsis:**

Managed (`/clr`) C++ project (`.dll`) statically links native C++ library (which is compiled with `/MD`). Static library is big and references a lot of other libraries, but functionality used by managed C++ code is trivial and shouldn't pull in any additional dependencies.

**Problems:**

1. linking fails with `LNK2001` and `LNK2019` mentioning symbols that code definitely does not depend on
2. even if I add required dependencies, switching toolset (e.g. migrating from `VS2017` to `VS2019`) causes errors to come back (this time mentioning other dependencies)

**What happens:**

Apparently, `/clr` switch causes compiler to treat inlined functions differently -- they are no longer get embedded into `.obj` files (as "weak symbols"), instead they get referenced in the table of imports. This means linker has to find things like:

```
"public: virtual char const * __cdecl std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UEBAPEBDXZ)
```

... which it does and (since CRT libraries are `DEFAULTLIB` and therefore are used last) typically it finds it in other library (namely, in aforementioned static native lib). So, it finds first `.obj` file in static lib that contains `std::exception::what()` and pulls it in -- meaning we now depend on everything said `.obj` depends. This explains problem #1 (bogus linker errors).

Now, if you compile your static lib with another toolset -- `obj` files can be stored in different order, causing problem #2.

To reproduce the issue you can use this code (make sure managed project links static lib):

```
//--------------------
// statlib.cpp
//
#include <exception>

void this_is_a_trap() { throw std::exception(); }

extern int bar();

int foo() { return bar(); }


//--------------------
// clrdll.cpp (managed code)
//
#include <exception>

__declspec(dllexport) void oops()
{
    throw std::exception();
}
```

If you link with `/VERBOSE` flag you'll see smth like:

```
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\oleaut32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\uuid.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\odbc32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\odbccp32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\tst\x64\Release\statlib.lib:
1>      Found "public: virtual char const * __cdecl std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UEBAPEBDXZ)
1>        Referenced in clrdll.obj
1>        Loaded statlib.lib(statlib.obj)   <-- Now we depend on `bar()`
```

**Question**

What is the best way to deal with this?

**Notes:**

- adding `msvcrt.lib` to linker inputs (before other static libs) helps, but not always -- certain symbols (such as `std::bad_weak_ptr::what()` aren't present in `msvcrt.lib`)
- this problem is the root cause for [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234152/weird-lnk2001-errors-after-migration-to-vs2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mixed (`/clr` and native) code `std::exception::what()` (and other similar symbols) **do** get inlined, but these definitions are *managed* (not native). Which normally is not an issue, but native code refers to *native* definition via `std::exception`'s vtable. Normally, such reference (once it fails to resolve) gets redirected to managed definition (which is generated, as stated above), but in this case -- native definition is found in another object (random object from native static library) before "redirection" kicks in, causing that object to be referenced.

See details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1140613/linking-native-c-static-library-causes-weird-behav.html). MS is figuring out a best way to deal with this.